# Keep icon bar floated right and wrap text around

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little header bar in html/css where there are a couple icons floated to the right side. I want them to remain in position and have the title (on the left) just wrap below if the area gets too small on the right side. Right now, my html looks like so (using bootstrap) :

```
 <div class="activity-panel-item--header">
     <div class="col-sm-8"><p>02 Development, LLC v. 607 South Park, LLC </p></div>
     <div class="col-sm-4"><span class="icon icon-trash-o pull-right"></span><span class="icon icon-cog2 pull-right"></span><span class="icon icon-pencil3 pull-right"></span></div>
</div>
```

So I have a col-sm-8 and col-sm-4. This will not work in the long run because col-sm-4 is too small in certain sizes, so I need to make the right column with the icon have a set width (140px lets say). So if a set a min-width on the right side it's going break on smaller sizes.

What I am wondering if, is there a way to let that title on the left side in the col-sm-8 move around the set width buttons on the right side when responsive (i basically want the buttons to stay in the same place the whole time). Something like if the buttons on the right were absolutely position but *not* out of the flow so the text reacts to it.

Here is a fiddle I was fooling with https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24085/

**EDIT**

So I improvised a solution by doing the following :
- taking the right icon-bar element out of the dom flow by absolutely positioning it and giving it a set with
- adding the same width as padding to the element wrapping both the left and the right items

I could then just do away with the col's all together. The code looks like so :

HTML:

```
  <div class="activity-panel-item col-md-12">
    <div class="activity-panel-item--header">

      <p>02 Development, LLC v. 607 South Park, LLC </p>
      <div class="activity-panel-item--header--iconbar">
        <span class="icon icon-trash-o pull-right">1</span><span class="icon icon-cog2 pull-right">2</span><span class="icon icon-pencil3 pull-right">3</span>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity-panel-item--body">
      <p>test 123345.</p>
      <h3></h3>
      <p>cases</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.activity-panel-item {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.activity-panel-item--header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 12px 125px 12px 12px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.activity-panel-item--header p {
  color: #fff;
}

.activity-panel-item--header .icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.activity-panel-item--body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.activity-title-input {
  width: 100%;
}

.activity-panel-item--header--iconbar {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 125px;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24114/

Any and all input would be helpful, or if anyone has a different working approach that would be great also. Thanks!

Comment: Bootstrap is not getting loaded in your fidddle.

Comment: @Valius79 updated it, thanks.

Comment: can you tell me for what purpose is it a footer or a header? the entire style what you have written is messed up by overriding almost all styles in ur css

Comment: @Aravind it's neither, it's a custom react component that has a little menu and title at the top of it, not a true header. If you look at the demo and drag it to small sizes you will notice the buttons become un-aligned and go below the text, I am trying to keep them in their same position and have the text form around them. The styles are a bit crazy, its a an enterprise project using a bunch of BEM, i am just trying to fix anothers work :).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without bootstrap `col-*-*` and by giving the explicit width to both divs, plus little extra style to your icon bar.

Updated Code

```
<div class="activity-panel-item--header">
  <div class="pull-left" style="width: 75%;">
    <p>02 Development, LLC v. 607 South Park, LLC </p>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; min-width: 25%;"><span class="icon icon-trash-o pull-right">1</span><span class="icon icon-cog2 pull-right">2</span><span class="icon icon-pencil3 pull-right">3</span></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24120/)

**EDIT 1**

If you think deeply according to this solution we both are at same point. Let me explain, I am giving **minimum width** 25% to icon bar and `75%` width to left element. That mean depending on situation width of icon bar can be increase but it must be at least `25%` of total screen or container and width of left element is `75%` that can be decrease depending on situation.

And you are giving width `125px` or any to icon bar that means it can be increase or decrease depending on situation but the original is `125px`

Here the situation I mean area and screen resolution. If icon are larger and not fit in `25%` then this width can be increase and left element can be decrease same is your edited case if icon bar not fit in `125px` then this width can be increase because we are not mentioning the maximum width to icon bar or minimum width to left element.

.

**EDIT 2**

I hope this is not illegal on stackoverflow to edit answer as many time as I need.

Apart from coding let’s do some math. Suppose we have 3 icon of (32x32) each. So the total width of icon wrapper will (32+32+32) `96px` add little margin of `12px` to each icon (12x3=36) on right side for beauty. Now the wrapper width is 96+36 = `132px`. And we are on device that has width of `400px`. My icon wrapper is (25%) `100px` of `400px` (device width) and your wrapper is `125px`. I am saying OK browser minimum width of icon wrapper is `100px` but if icons are larger and not fit in `100px` you can increase this width according to you need, In this case it will increase `100px` to `132px` or any. But I don't want to break these icons to next line. They should be display in their original size and style (32x32) plus margin. You can break left content (text) to wrap around these icons but don't break the icons itself. They should retain their original size. No matter what ever device width is. Browser, Please don't decrease the icon size just increase wrapper width.

And your `125px` is less than `132px`. So your wrapper will break and one of its icon will move to next line. Until you have to go to you CSS and explicitly wrote `132px` or any in `width`. And what if after one month your boss said please place icon of 40x40 and after 3 month and so on...?

Try it, place larger icons and see what happens to your `width: 125px`.

Comment: % with on the icon (right) bar will not work as that is too small on smaller screens . As mentioned in the question I probably need a min width but it will break this Css logic

Comment: @ajmajmajma your problem is very interesting :) I'm working on since you post it. Yes, but there is no other way I think.

Comment: I figured out a way of doing it - check my edit to the question, but if you have a better way of doing it I would love to see it!

Comment: Your edit is appreciated :) Only the major difference in my solution and your edit I am giving width in % and you giving fixed width to icon bar and pulling left element out of DOM.

Comment: Hey friend, this still will not work as this header item gets really small on the page (sometimes 100-150px wide), so the % approach cannot work for this scenario, unless I start making a ton of custom media queries and add in custom js to read the size of the box (and not the screen) because the box is in a grid of items that can be resized so it can be 200 px wide while the screen is still 800+px wide.

Comment: You are talking about small resolution. But just assume if you are viewing this header item on iPad or any device where resolution 800px+ in wide  then 125px is OK or 200px (in %)? Icon looks really small  there in 125px. and I hope you are not getting bore from this debate :)

Comment: Take a look - https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24114/ . Drag it from full size to tiny. the icon bar stays on the right side keeping in the same size it needs to and the left text does not break above or below, that is the intended behaviour. If I were to add more icons, I would probably need to add a little more than 125, but it needs to be a static size so it does not break, thus % cannot work for this scenario. Maybe if you did % and a min-width, but that will still break the title because it will be expecting, say 75%, and min with 125px is more than 25% on a very small size.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am totally misunderstanding you.. here is a easy method. Too much CSS 
classes so I used my own but you get the concept.

```
<div class="top">
<div class="content1">
    <p>02 Development, LLC v. 607 South Park, LLC </p>
</div>
<div class="content2">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="content3">
    <p>test 123345.</p>
    <h3>Nothing Here</h3>
    <p>cases</p>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/ovo83p5k/

Comment: So the difference between your solution and mine is where you put the padding (on the left "title" part rather than the outer bit), and you used % for the right side padding, and you used `fixed` vs `absolute`. The % will not work, if you drag the screen to like 200 px wide, you will see overlap because of this. The fixed vs absolute is the same thing though, both take the div out of the dom flow.

Comment: Yours does not wrap as you said you would like it to. Yours is in 2 columns . In that regards all you have to do is decrease font size. What I do not understand is why down to 200px. Is there a phone or device around that would require it to scale to that size?

Comment: Changing the font size is not possible in this case per the requirements. it can get smaller than that, it does not fill the entire screen so you can get that small even on desktop. my solution does not wrap the text under it true, but it stops the overlap and keeps both the text and icon bar the correct size.